# How to display an option by default in <select> if the values are coming dynamically from rest call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, meteor

I had a  field where the values to it come from a service and I am displaying in the select field using ng-options.But by default I want to display the first option.

Html

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<select class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track by 
traderTypeObj.type">
</select>
</div>
```

js:

```
 if(results.data.traderTypes.status.code == 200){
 for(let i= 0; i< results.data.traderTypes.body.length ; i++ ){
 let keyVal = {};
 keyVal.type = results.data.traderTypes.body[i].ITTD_TRADER_TYPE_CODE;
 keyVal.description = results.data.traderTypes.body[i].ITTD_TRADER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION;
 $scope.traderTypes.push(keyVal); 
  }
  }
  if($rootScope.customerDetails != null &&$rootScope.customerDetails.natureOfBusiness != null && $rootScope.customerDetails.traderType !=
 null){
 for(let i=0; i < $scope.businessTypes.length ; i++ ){
 if($scope.businessTypes[i].description == $rootScope.customerDetails.natureOfBusiness.description){                                 $rootScope.customerDetails.natureOfBusiness.type =
 $scope.businessTypes[i].type;

}
}
for(let i=0; i < $scope.traderTypes.length ; i++ ){

 if($scope.traderTypes[i].description == $rootScope.customerDetails.traderType.description){$rootScope.customerDetails.traderType.type = $scope.traderTypes[i].type;
                                  }   $rootScope.customerDetails.traderType=$scope.traderTypes[0].description;
                                } 

$scope.$apply();  

     }}

                      }
```

Iam trying to display first option from by default..Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can use,which on init will set your first option on default,

```
ng-init="$root.customerDetails.traderType = options[0]"

// In HTML

<select class="form-control" id="select" ng-
model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track
by traderTypeObj.type" ng-init="$root.customerDetails.traderType =
options[0]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init

```
   <select class="form-control" id="select" ng-init="$root.customerDetails.traderType = traderTypes[0]"  ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
    ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track by 
    traderTypeObj.type">
```

Comment: Tried..But no luck

Comment: it does not set the initial value?

Answer (score 0):

you can save default option value in model for example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track by 
traderTypeObj.type">
```

And in service store value like: 
  if you have id field then 0 or else value "abc"

```
$root.customerDetails.traderType = 0; 
or
$root.customerDetails.traderType = "abc";
```

Comment: yes ..but we need to display only values from the service or else another call fill fail

Comment: its properly working for me in scope variable. with same critaria.

Comment: We are not sure what the values are coming to select..so I cant set that..Im trying to achieve this since validation is not working for <select>..If user enters submit button without selecting one option,the next call fails..So  i want to select one by default so that next call wont fail

Comment: so use don't know want values going to bind in dropdown.

Comment: I didnt get your above comment

Comment: You do not know which values going to populate dropdown?

Comment: They arevcoming from a service...So not sure that all the values will be same eveytime

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one :

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
    ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track by 
    traderTypeObj.type">
        <option value="DefaultOption">Your default option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It  cant be text...Im trinng to achieve this since validation is not working for <select>..If user enters submit button without selecting one the next call fails..So that i want to select one by default